# How to add multiple Auth in flm.php for unisharp/laravel-filemanager

Tags: laravel, file-manager

i am using laravel 5 4 and "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "~1.8"

in my project i have multiple Auth like member, client, manager, reseller but only manager and client have access to file upload.
here is my flm.php

```
'middlewares' => ['web', 'auth:client', 'auth:manager'],
```

this it not working.
but
'middlewares' => ['web', 'auth:client'], // working but only client can upload but manager can't upload
or
'middlewares' => ['web', 'auth:manager'], // working but only manager can upload but client can't upload

i also tried to use but it not working too
'user_field' => App\Handlers\ConfigHandler::class,
and handlers config

```
if (Auth::guard('client')->check()) {
  return Auth::guard('client')->user()->id;
}
if (Auth::guard('manager')->check()) {
  return Auth::guard('manager')->user()->id;
}
```

i need middlewares working for both client and manager

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had this same issue in Laravel 5.4 here's how I solved it. 
first in the laravel-filemanager routes in web.php, i did this.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth:manager,client']], function () {
 \UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
});
```

web is the default guard, vendor is a custom guard...in your case it would be `auth:manager,client`
then to avoid users having the same folder names, I needed same folder for all admins(managers) and then the client guard uses `auth()->user()->id`, i changed laravel-filemanager ConfigHandler to this

```
<?php
namespace UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Handlers;
class ConfigHandler
{
    public function userField()
    {
        if(auth('vendor')->check())
    {      
        return auth()->user()->id;
    }
    else
    {
        return 'admin';
    }
}

   /*public function userField()
     {
    return auth()->user()->id;
     }*/
}
```

Hope it helps.